# Selection based on string containing one or many other strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table 'forms' with a column 'title'.
Inside my stored procedure I create a temp table '#temp1' with the column 'searchVals'.

Multiple strings are parsed into the stored procedure, the number of strings is variable.

What I'm trying to achieve is selecting a row if the 'title' contains one or many 'searchVal'. But I haven't been able to achieve this successfully yet.

For example something like this

`SELECT title FROM #temp1 WHERE title IN ('%'+(SELECT searchVal FROM #temp1)+'%')`

The issue is obviously that IN doesn't allow wildcards but if it did, this is the type of result I'm trying to achieve.
Stacking ORs also doesn't work as the number of rows in #temp1 is variable.
Predicate and free-text searches don't work as the forms database isn't indexed appropriately.

I've come up with what I think is a valid solution but I can't seem to construct it correctly. The function would be called from the WHERE clause and return a boolean. I'm sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I did search extensively.
Below is my proposed solution with pseudocode code where I'm not sure of the interchangeable SQL code.

```
DECLARE FUNCTION dbo.checkVal(searchVal column, formTitle varchar)
RETURNS boolean
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE (not end of column)
        IF formTitle LIKE '%'+searchVal+'%'
            RETURN true
        END
    END
RETURN FALSE
END
```

Sorry for my inconsistent and incorrect SQL code. I would appreciate any suggestions or corrections that would make my code work. Better solutions are welcome too.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to check every row of forms by an `EXISTS()`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM forms f 
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM #temp1 
    WHERE f.title LIKE '%' + searchVals + '%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator in a JOIN statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.*
FROM forms f
JOIN #temp1 t ON f.title LIKE '%' + t.column + '%'
```

But keep in mind that using the LIKE operator does come with a performance hit so you will want to reduce the number of rows in the forms table using a where clause if possible